# Using Angular Service to pass information between views with the same controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, ngresource, angularjs-factory

I have a multistep form accross several views that share a controller.  Here are the routes:

```
.state('tab.newEventCategory', {
  url: '/activities/new-event-category',
  views: {
    'tab-patient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/new-event-category.html',
      controller: 'ActivityDashboardCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.newEventSubCategory', {
  url: '/activities/new-event-sub-category',
  views: {
    'tab-patient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/new-event-sub-category.html',
                controller: 'ActivityDashboardCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.selectEventAttendees', {
  url: '/activities/select-event-attendees',
  views: {
    'tab-patient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/select-event-attendees.html',
      controller: 'ActivityDashboardCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.addPictures', {
  url: '/activities/add-pictures',
  views: {
    'tab-patient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/add-pictures.html',
      controller: 'ActivityDashboardCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I am trying to make it so that as a user goes through the form his answers will be saved to a variable called `formData`. Here is the controller:

```
.controller('ActivityDashboardCtrl', function($scope, $state, EventCategory, EventForm, EventSubCategory, Patient, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPlatform, CreateEvent) {

  $scope.formData = CreateEvent;
  $scope.event_categories = EventCategory.query();
  $scope.event_sub_categories = EventSubCategory.query();
  $scope.patients = Patient.query({facility_user_id: 1});

  $scope.moveToEventSubCategory = function(event_category){
    $scope.formData.category = event_category;
    $state.go('tab.newEventSubCategory');
  }
  $scope.createSubCategory = function(sub_categories){
    $state.go('tab.selectEventAttendees');
  }

  $scope.addAttendeesToFormData = function(event_attendees){
    $state.go('tab.addPictures');
  }

  $scope.saveForm = function(){
      $scope.formData.$save();
  }

});
```

I am new to Angular and I am finding it somewhat difficult to understand how services work.

As you can see in the code above, at the first part of the form, $scope.formData is set to the CreateEvent service:

```
.factory('CreateEvent', function($resource){
  return $resource("http://localhost:3000/api/events");
})
```

Here is the first page of the form.  When this part is submitted, the `moveToEventSubCategory` function is called:

```
<ion-view view-title="Activity Dashboard">
  <ion-content>

    <div ng-repeat="event_category in event_categories" class="padding">
        <a class="button button-block button-positive button-large" ng-click="moveToEventSubCategory(event_category)">
          {{event_category}}
        </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is succesfully passing information to the next page of the form because the expressions on that page are evaluating properly with formData.  On the second page, the user picks subcategories:

```
<!-- client/app/views/main.html -->
<ion-view view-title="New Event Subcategory">
    <ion-content class="padding">
    formData Category:
    {{formData.category}}
    <form ng-submit="createSubCategory(formData)">
        <div ng-repeat="sub_category in event_sub_categories">
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="formData.subcategories[sub_category]" ng-true-value="'{{sub_category}}'">
              {{sub_category}}</ion-checkbox>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Continue</button>
    </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

On the final page, I want to send the information to the server, so I have:

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="saveForm()">
    Submit
</button>
```

When clicking on the button, I get the following error in my browser console:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: $scope.formData.$save is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.saveForm (controllers.js:54)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:26457), <anonymous>:4:215)
    at ionic.bundle.js:62386
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29257)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:62385)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16583)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2948)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2937)
    at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (ionic.bundle.js:3013)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25642(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:22421Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29259(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:62385eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16583triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2948tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2937tapMouseUp @ ionic.bundle.js:3013
```

Can someone please give me a good explanation as to how services work to pass information between views and also specifically how to fix the error I'm getting?

UPDATE:

Based on some feedback, I've rewritten the service to this:

```
.factory('CreateEvent', function($resource){
  // var eventFormData = eventFormData || {};
  // return $resource("http://localhost:3000/api/events");
          var formData = {};

          return {
            getFormData:function(){
                     return formData;
            },
            setCategory:function(category){
                  formData.category = category;
            },

            setSubCategories:function(sub_categories){
              formData.sub_categories = sub_categories;
            },

            createEvent:function(){
              return $resource("http://localhost:3000/api/events");
            }
        } 
})
```

Then to save object with an api call i do `$scope.formData.createEvent().$save();` but I am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To exchange data with a service you can use something like that:

Create a service

```
    .factory('objectService', function($resource){
        var internalObj = {};
        var myRes = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
        return {
            setObject:function(obj){
                  internalObj = obj;
            },
            getObject:function(){
                     return internalObj;
            },
            updateObject:functon(){
                 internalObject = myRes.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
                     user.abc = true;
                     user.$save();
                 });
             }
        } 
     })
```

Set data from controller1

```
.controller('controller1', function(objectService) {
     var obj = {
         number: 12,
         text: "hello world"
     }
     objectService.setObject(obj);
}
```

Get data in controller2

```
.controller('controller2', function(objectService) {
     var obj = objectService.getObject();
}
```

I can't help you with your javascript error, but the problem is, that `CreateEvent` isn't a object with function `$save()`

Comment: Thanks, but with this service it no longer returns the $resource function so it  can't make the api call.  How do I combine the new service you wrote with the $resource function?

Comment: I add a new function in the service including `$resource`.

Comment: Thanks but this is for updating an object.  I only want to create an object.  Also where did you get user from?

Comment: All function names are just for demonstration. They all are nonsense. I don't know your requirements. You can rename the function to `createObject` if you want. And you can replace everything with the `$resource`

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't get $resource to work.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting the error because 'CreateEvent' does not have a function called save(). as for how services work to pass information between controllers:

edit: upon doing more research, 'CreateEvent' should have a function called save() by default.

```
angular.module('mainModule').service('someService',['$http', function($http){

     var sharedObject = {};

     this.getObject = function(){
      return sharedObject;
  };
  this.setObjectData = function(something){
      sharedObject.data = something;
  };

        // EDIT

        // $http call
        this.httpQuery = function(){
            return $http.get('api/users').then(
                function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
        };

    // $resource call, which is somewhat the same as the one you wrote
    var resourceQuery = $resource('/users/:userId', { userId:'@userId'});
    // might be unnecessary
    this.getResource = function(){
        return resourceQuery;
    };
    // END EDIT

}]);

    // Edit: to use on controllers:

// $http
someService.httpQuery().then(
    function(data){
        // do something with data.
        console.log(response)
    });

// $resource
var someData = [1,2,3,4];
var user = someService.getResource().get({id:2});
user.$promise.then(
    function(data)
        // do something with data.
        console.log(data);
    });

// END EDIT
angular.module('mainModule').controller('controller1', [$'$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService){
        // $scope.objectData is now bound to someService's sharedObject var
        // and will be updated when sharedObject is changed (when setObjectData function is called from wherever)
        $scope.objectData = someService.getObject();
    }]);

angular.module('mainModule').controller('controller2', ['$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService){
 var someArray = [1,2,3,4];
        // the sharedObject.data in someService is now an array [1,2,3,4]
        $scope.setObjectData = someService.setObjectData(someArray); 
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this service it no longer returns the $resource function so it  can't make the api call.  How do I combine the new service you wrote with the $resource function?

Comment: @Philip7899 i'm a little bit unfamiliar with $resource, but i'll try. i'll add it in the edit.